# Weird memory corruption

Tags: c++, memory-management, stack, libusb

This error only is occuring when I build with the WinDDK nmake compiler in 'free' (release), which performs optimizations. I can't reproduce this in the 'checked' build or compiling with VS.

Here is pseudo-code of what is happening in my code:

```
main()
{
   //variable init and other code
    fprintf(log, "pre nullValue: %lu\n", NULL);  //printf added for debugging
   otherFunc();
   funcWithError(str1, str2, NULL);
    fprintf(log, "post nullValue: %lu\n", NULL); 
    fprintf(log, "post2 nullValue: %lu, %lu, %lu\n", NULL, 0, NULL);
}

BOOL otherFunc()
{
   //variable init and other code
   callToDll();
    //...doing stuff
   libusb_usb_open(var1);    //If I remove this line there is no problem!!
    //...doing more stuff
}

BOOL funcWithError(char* s1, char* s2, FUNC_PTR fp)
{
    fprintf(log, "inFunc nullValue: %lu, %lu\n", NULL, fp);
   if(fp != NULL)
      return FALSE;        //This line is being executed erroneously!!
}
```

> *Output in log:*
>   pre nullValue: 0
>   inFunc nullValue: 0, 251208
>   post nullValue: 251208
>   post2 nullValue: 251208, 251208, 251208
>   *Note: The re-occurring number (251208) is a different number each time the program is run*

Just changing that one line fixes/causes it. It is the [libusb usb_open](http://libusb.sourceforge.net/doc/function.usbopen.html) call.

1. Ultimately my question is to figure out how to fix the problem (I can't avoid that call)
2. But just **on a stack/memory management level how is it even possible to have NULL not zero and have a literal value '0' print as non zero?**

let me know what other information might help...

Comment: Maybe something is wrong with argument passing conventions to libusb_usb_open and this cause some stack corruption. Is this 64 bit app? Maybe you should use %llu instead of %lu. The best way to find out what is wrong will be to debug this part of code in assembler and check whats going on.

Comment: Yeah I am trying to save looking through assembly, so thought I would post. It is compiling for x86 on an x86 machine, so not 64bit. So %llu does nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a completely slamdunk.  But it is very likely that the stack is getting imbalanced.  In the debugger (yes, you can debug the release build), check the value of the ESP register before and after the call.  It should be the same.  It won't be if the calling convention for the function is wrong.  Like __stdcall vs __cdecl.

This can hide itself well when you build programs with nmake.exe, it is easy to forget to turn on the /RTCs option in the debug build so stack checking code is emitted.  And the ESP register tends to restore itself on a function return.  Until you build the release version where functions get inlined and usage of EBP is optimized away so ESP doesn't restore itself anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Update: So, I finally got windbg to break into the dll and examine some things. It was, as I originally suspected and Hans noted, a corruption of the stack caused by a mismatched calling convention.

What made it visible in only the release build was that the compiler optimized the 0/Null values to be using the ebx register value rather than passing 0. In OtherFunc() the optimizations used ebx to store several other values, then the call to Usb_Open() corrupted the stack, then when OtherFunc() tried to pop the stack to restore the original ebx value, it restored garbage rather than '0'. So, back in main() every optimized reference to NULL was using this garbage value.

Note: The reason the other dll calls didn't corrupt the stack was because they were parameterless.

So in conclusion the answers:

1. Call libusb using the right convention (libusb uses the __cdecl calling convention, NMAKE uses __stdcall by default)
2. Even though NULL and '0' are hard coded in the source code, the compiler can optimize to use a register rather than pass a value, and registers are subject to corruption from bad code.